# How can i display a string adding a hyphen each word on PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I display a string, separating each letter by a dash with a for loop?

For example i want to display:

h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d

I tried with the **substr** function but I can't get it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it must be PL/SQL and `FOR` loop, then you could

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str  varchar2(20) := 'helloworld';
  3    retval varchar2(50);
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. length(l_str) loop
  6      retval := retval || substr(l_str, i, 1) ||'-';
  7    end loop;
  8    retval := rtrim(retval, '-');
  9    dbms_output.put_line(retval);
 10  end;
 11  /
h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Otherwise, consider e.g.

```
SQL> select rtrim(regexp_replace('helloworld', '(.)', '\1-'), '-') result from dual;

RESULT
-------------------
h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d

SQL>
```

or

```
SQL> select listagg(substr('helloworld', level, 1), '-') within group (order by level) result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= length('helloworld');

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d

SQL>
```

Comment: the one with the listagg looks brilliant

Answer (score 0):

You can just output each successive character and, after the first, output a hyphen between them:

```sql
DECLARE
  string VARCHAR2(20) := 'helloworld';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(SUBSTR(string, 1, 1));
  FOR i IN 2 .. LENGTH(string)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(SUBSTR(string, i, 1));
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d
> ```

---

If you want to do it without loops then you can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  string VARCHAR2(20) := 'helloworld';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '(.)', '-\1'), 2) );
END;
/
```

You should not use `LTRIM` (or `RTRIM`) to remove the hyphens as, if the input string has leading (or trailing) hyphens then these would be removed from the output and that would be erroneous.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE
  string VARCHAR2(20) := '--helloworld--';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Correct:');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '(.)', '-\1'), 2));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Incorrect:');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '(.)', '-\1'), '-'));
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Correct:
> ----h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d----
> Incorrect:
> h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d----
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=585e8b56326c22e12daf085f76d35119)*